# How to rotate SVG path without clipping and without increasing container <svg> height/width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

Is it possible to rotate an svg path without clipping it? I'm aware that I can increase the size of the  container, but I don't want to do this. I tried to rotate the svg container at the same angle as the path, but it doesn't work.

This is my basic svg setup:

```
<svg width = {600} height = {600} viewBox = "0 0 600 600">
<svg x = {10} y = {10} height = {40} width = {100} viewBox = "0 0 100 40">
<path d= {"M0 0 L100 40 M0 40 L100 0"} />
</svg>
<svg>
```

If I add `transform={rotate(90)} transform-origin="50% 50%"` to the path element, then the element rotates, but gets cutoff by the svg.

If I instead add that same code to the parent svg (the 100 width one), then absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: Just added my code.

Comment: There are multiple ways your question can be solved: the path should remain at a constant size, but fit inside its container regardless of the rotation, or the path should be rescaled dependent on the rotation such that its [bounding box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/bounding_box) always fills the container at maximum size. Which variant do you want to achieve?

Comment: The path should remain at a constant size, but still fit inside the container regardless of rotation. I guess this means I'm fine with rotating the container, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow: visible` to the svg element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reserve enough space for your path to rotate in. Without changing the container size, you can define the `viewBox` to include all the coordinates where the rotated path could end at. That rectangle will then be fitted into your container.

If you rotate the path around its center at `(50, 20)`, its upper limit with a rotation of 90deg will end at `y=-30`. The `viewBox` needs to include that value.

Your code also indicates you want to move the path `+10, +10` away from the upper left corner. To achieve that and leave it at its original size, set `viewBox="-10 -40 600 600"`. That rectangle will be fit into your outer `<svg>`, without the need to define an inner one.

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="-10 -40 600 600">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 40 M0 40 L100 0" stroke="red" />
  <path transform="rotate(90, 50, 20)" d="M0 0 L100 40 M0 40 L100 0" stroke="blue" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it depends on the use case.
Here are two examples that might help where I place the cross using the transform attribute.
The red cross is your original path where 0,0 is in the upper left corner.
Here I translate the first and then rotate.
The same happens with the blue cross, but here I have moved 0,0 to the middle of the cross.
This can help in cases where the element needs to rotate a lot or copied around.

```css
svg {
  border: solid thin black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M0 0 L100 40 M0 40 L100 0"
  transform="translate(70 0) rotate(90)"
  stroke="blue" />
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M -50 -20 L 50 20 M -50 20 L 50 -20"
  transform="translate(50 50) rotate(90)"
  stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the great answers. I haven't tested all the solutions yet, but I bet that each answer works best for different situations. However, I figured out a way that worked best for me. As shown in my question, I do have a "parent" svg that is quite large, but I needed help rotating the smaller svg properly while making sure paths/polygons inisde the smaller svg don't clip. I ended up surrounding the "small" svg tag with a g tag, and then applied the rotation transform to the g tag. This made the svg as a whole rotate, and rotated the inner contents of the svg as well. The end result looked something like this:

```
<svg width = {600} height = {600} viewBox = "0 0 600 600">
<g transform = "rotate(90)">
<svg x = {10} y = {10} height = {40} width = {100} viewBox = "0 0 100 40">
<path d= {"M0 0 L100 40 M0 40 L100 0"} />
</svg>
</g>
<svg>
```

It did look a little bit different since I was using React.js, but that was the gist of it.